# Magento2 - Reload JS file after ajax call

Tags: magento2, javascript, magento2.2, ajax

After the ajax call my new elements which are created are not recognized by the event handlers in my jQuery code.

Is there a way to reload the JS file when the ajax URL is called?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that your click events are not being picked up on newly created elements you can use [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/). Meaning there is no need to reload a whole JS file.

So rather than creating an event binding like so:

```
$( ".example" ).on( "click", function( event ) {
    ...
});
```

You attach it to a parent element like so:

```
$( ".examples-parent" ).on( "click", ".example", function( event ) {
    ...
});
```

Comment: No my product gallery and tabs are not working in my quickview after I retrieve products with my ajax request